# Browser extension to automatically fill in two factor one time password

Tags: web-browser, two-factor-authentication, browser-extension

I am looking for a browser extension that generates a one time password for a two factor authentication and automatically fills this into the corresponding form of the website.

I know [The Authenticator](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/auth-helper/) extension. But in this case I have to copy it manually to the form.

The secret should be stored locally.

I am using firefox, but it would be ok to use another browser which runs on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Try **keepassxc**. It has the Firefox extension with autofill and stores all data locally, + desktop app.